# Delivering Javascript Files Securely When Using HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, https

My asp.net mvc application runs under https and it is working just fine.
The problem is when a user goes to the secure portion of the website they get the warning asking them if they want to view only to content that was delivered securely. If they click yes, then non on the javascript or jquery will work. If they select no, then it all works just fine.
How then can I provide the .js files securely? Or is that totally up to the user?
Also the warning gets very annoying at it shows it on every new page that is navigated to.
thanks!
also, this is only a problem when the user is using IE, Firefox has no issues

Comment: Use "https" in the URLs referencing the JavaScript files...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

twal,

use the following approach and it should fix the issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js") %>"></script>
```

this will then use the approriate path to the file resolving the protocol on it's way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're referencing HTTPS for full URL.

You can often avoid this if they are relative URL as it will normally use the same protocol you are currently on.

Comment: ok i am referencing the files like this: <script src="../../Scripts/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>